# Inject configuration into ASP Core correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

We host a ASP Core web api inside a service fabric instance. I want to forward all configs to the Core app. I use this method

https://dzimchuk.net/configuring-asp-net-core-applications-in-service-fabric/

And then I invoke it using `ConfigureAppConfiguration`

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                return new WebHostBuilder()
                            .UseKestrel()
                            .ConfigureServices(
                                services => services.AddSingleton(serviceContext))
                            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => builder.AddServiceFabricConfiguration(serviceContext))
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseReverseProxyIntegration)
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build();
            }))
    };
}
```

The inected configration in startup class do have the configs applied, like connection string and logging

[image]

But it seems its not fully jacked into the framework.

For example I need to explicit supply ApplicationInsights with the config `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);` otherwise it does not pickup the instrument key. And the logging does not work (the log level is not applied).

**Update:**

I tried doing a custom config provider in a standard core project without service fabric and it works.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => builder.AddServiceFabricConfiguration())
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

internal class ServiceFabricConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{

    public override void Load()
    {
        Data["Logging:Debug:LogLevel:Default"] = "Information";
    }
}

internal class ServiceFabricConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{


    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new ServiceFabricConfigurationProvider();
    }
}

public static class ServiceFabricConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddServiceFabricConfiguration(this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Add(new ServiceFabricConfigurationSource());
        return builder;
    }
}
```

So it seems something i service fabric land is not working as it should.

edit: Repro project https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/ServiceFabricLoggingRepro

Comment: If i understand your question, you think that the configuration should be injected to ApplicationInsights. 
But this is not the case. Your described approach is correct, see also here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration

Comment: Its not app.insight related per se. Its rather that the config seems not to pickup it up. For example my logging settings (not appinsight but debug logger) does not work. edit: when app insight works as it should you do not need to supply it with Configuration, I got it working with our vanilla COre app when not hosted in service fabric by just calling AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() with empty method signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service fabric project template is different from the standard Core project.

Service fabric project template does

```
return new WebHostBuilder()
```

While the standard core project template does

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
```

I have suggested Microsoft to unify their project templates
https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/319#issuecomment-486116026

I also mentioned Application insights above. Its not directly related. Application insights do not inject IConfiguration, but rather look for the json file. I would say this is a bug, but it would be a breaking change fixit it

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/867